# Magento Special Price to change grouped.phtml table

Tags: price, magento-1, special-price

I am trying to edit our `grouped.phtml` table so that when a product has a special price it displays different columns.
I have edited my `grouped.phtml` page to include these columns but can not work out the correct PHP statements to make them show only when a product has a 'special price'.

I have tried:
`<?php if($_product->getSpecialPrice() ): ?>` and also `<?php if($_product->getSpecialPrice()){ ?>` but this does not seem to work.

I have also found another post showing how to display an icon for products with special price: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590849/dsplay-sale-icon-on-special-price-products-in-magento-only-at-homepage-it-is-sh

But again this doesn't not work for me.

Comment: This belongs on the Magento stackexchange site.  I've flagged it for migration

Comment: @DavidWilkins Thanks, sorry didn't realise I posted it on the wrong site. Is it something I can do to migrate?

Comment: This should work: `$currentProduct->getSpecialPrice()` are you on the catalog category view or on the product detail page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the stock template:

```
<?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
    <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_item, $_item->getFinalPrice(), true) ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></td>
        <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
        <td class="a-right">
            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <td class="a-center">
        <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
            <input type="text" name="super_group[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>]" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $_item->getQty()*1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php else: ?>
            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You will need to use `$_item->getSpecialPrice()` and ensure that `special_price` is set to show in product listing in attribute management.